# Convert List to Slice in Spring

Tags: java, spring, slice, pageable

So my question is simple, I am getting a `Slice<Object>` from database using pageable.

Then I need to filter it based on some parameters(fe. status), so as usual I'm doing something like this:

`slice.getContent().stream().filter(o -> o.getStatus().equals(status)).collect(Collectors.toList())`

But I still need to return the `Slice<Object>`. How can I correctly convert the result of filtering into `Slice<Object>`?

I know about the `SliceImpl<>`, which requires 3 arguments `List<T> content, Pageable pageable, boolean hasNext` but how do I correctly determine the `pageable` and the `hasNext` of my filtered list? Is there a quick and easy way that I don't know of?

Comment: You can use `Unpaged` instance for Pageable argument, and for `hasNext` you can use any of true/false if you don't need it in your next steps

Comment: Why do you need to filter the contents in memory? Of course there's no way to determine `hasNext`, the final page might contain all the wrong statuses, for example.